# How to convert Json object with ref attribute into c# class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have below json object to convert for c# class.

```
{
   "Token": “Token”,
   "ref": 1 
}
```

The converted c# class is given below.

```
public class ABC
{
public string Token{get;set;}
public int ref{get;set;}
}
```

But I received following error message from c#.

**Member modifier 'ref' must precede the member type and name**

How do I convert JSON into c# class correctly with ref attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Newtonsoft.Json`, you could do this:

```
public class ABC
{
    public string Token{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("ref")]
    public int Ref{get;set;}
}
```

If you don't want to do that or can't do that, use this:

```
public class ABC
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int @ref {get; set; }
}
```

Since `ref` is a C# keyword, you can add the `@` symbol which allows you to use it as a property name.

```
var thing = new ABC { @ref = 0 };
thing.@ref = 5;
```

Your models will serialize as if it were defined as `ref`.

Comment: Thank you. [JsonProperty("ref")] worked!